# creating a python rpm to install

Tags: python, packaging, gnome, rpm

I have created a dead simple gtk python app (just a pycairo animation) for gnome.

I am trying to make an rpm so that it is easy for others to install it.  I was hoping to make my app appear in the gnome application menu. I am running into trouble when I try to install it on Fedora 13 (my own box).

I follow the instructions here:
http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html

and am able to dynamically create a `TestApp-1.1.tar.gz`, `TestApp-1.1-1.noarch.rpm`, and `TestApp-1.1-1.src.rpm`.

But when I double click on `TestApp-1.1-1.noarch.rpm` two things happen:

1. I click a dialog, accepting to install.  Then, the software apparently installs, according to another dialog ("Finished").  But then another dialog comes up on top of the finished dialog to say:

   > > "Additional confirmation required / To install this file, additional software also has to be modified.  The following software needs to be installed: `TestApp-1.1-1 (noarch)`".

   When I agree to this dialog, it looks like it is checking stuff out online... or just taking a long time.  This whole procedure is a little confusing... is this normal?
2. Once installed, only one file is installed - `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/TestApp-1.1-py2.6.egg-info`.  What is an egg-info file?  Where is my application?

When I double click on the `TestApp-1.1-1.src.rpm`, I get this error in a modal dialog:

> > "could not do simulate: Backend will not install a src rpm file"

I would appreciate any help on how to make an installable python application for gnome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the spec from the generated SRPM and then clean it up as per the Fedora Packaging guidelines.

["Packaging:Guidelines"](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines)

["Packaging:Python"](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python)

Comment: Sorry to be so ignorant... but (1) which of the three files I have generated (TestApp-1.1.tar.gz, TestApp-1.1-1.noarch.rpm, and TestApp-1.1-1.src.rpm) is the SRPM and (2) which file is the spec?  I opened the .tar.gz and found a PKG-INFO in there, but I don't think that is what I am looking for.

Comment: $ rpm2cpio TestApp-1.1-1.src.rpm | cpio -idmv  ( http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html )

Comment: I guess what I need is a simple spec file for a python app on fedora...  any suggestions?

Comment: `rpmdev-newspec -t python python-foo.spec`

Comment: Thank you.  That creates a spec which, when I modify to provide my source tar.gz, and a name, desc, etc. Then I call rpmbuild -ba python-foo.spec... results in ~/rpmbuild/ files with the same problems I have listed in the o.p.  I guess I need a more fleshed out simple sample spec file.  Alas, I am obviously new to this.

Comment: The problem is likely in the `setup.py` then.